# Swift's Great Mystery

Tags: identification-request, jonathan-swift

In his best known book, *History of Shit*, Dominique Laporte mentions "Swift's *Great Mystery*" when listing pertinent literature (pp. 100-101):

> The *Biblioteca Scatalogica* furnishes an impressive list of works, for the most part in Latin, published between the sixteenth and the nineteenth centuries. In the sixteenth century, we find the *De excrementis*, [...] followed, in order of publication, by *Dissertatio de utilitate inspiciendorum ut signorum* (1693), [...], Swift’s magestrial [*sic*] two-volume *Great Mystery* published in 1726,...

The year of publication seems to correspond with Swift's lifetime (indeed, *Gulliver's Travels* was published that same year), but I'm having a hard time finding which of his works (if anything) this is referencing. I'm not especially enthusiastic about reading it, but mostly wondering about Laporte's integrity -- does the *Great Mystery* actually exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laporte must refer to *The Grand Mystery: Or, Art of Meditating Over an House of Office, Restor'd and Unveil'd*, published in 1726; whether this is to be attributed to Swift or to Edward Ward is apparently unclear. A modern reproduction is for sale [online](https://www.bookdepository.com/Grand-Mystery-Jonathan-Swift/9781245694889) but I couldn't find any more information on this book.