# What is the evidence that Jonathan Swift wrote "The Grand Mystery"?

Tags: essays, jonathan-swift, authorship

In his [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/11925/289) to [Swift's Great Mystery](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/11921/swifts-great-mystery), @Jos states that whether *The Grand Mystery* (1726) "is to be attributed to Swift or to Edward Ward is apparently unclear." An edition of the entire booklet is available on the [Hathi Trust website](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101067499028&seq=1). The title page reads, in full:

> The Grand Mystery: Or, Art of Meditating over an Houſe of Office, Reſtor'd and Unveil'd; After the Manner of the Ingenious Dr. S——ft. With Observations Hiſtorical, Political, and Moral; Shewing the Derivation of this Science from the Chaldees and Ægyptians; with the particular Practice of all Nations on this important Subject.
>
> Alſo Proposals at large for eſtablishing a Corporation for erecting 500 publick Offices of Ease within the Cities of London and Weſtminster, for the Conveniency of the Nobility and Gentry of both Sexes, in the Natural Neſſeities; which beſides the Advantages that will thereby accrue to this noble Metropolis in particular, will enable the Company to divide above a Million per Ann. to the great Benefit alſo of every Proprietor.
>
> ---
>
> Dedicated to the profound Dr. W————d, and ſeriouſly recommended to all Perſons that drink the Mineral Waters of Pyrmont, Briſtol, Bath, Tunbridge, Epſom, Scarborough, Acton, Dullege, Richmond, Iſlington, &c.
>
> ---
>
> The Second Edition corrected.
>
> ---
>
> LONDON: Printed for J.Roberts near the Oxford Arms in Warwick-Lane, and Sold by the Bookſellers of London and Weſtminſter. 1726. (Price 6 d.)

Neither on this page nor anywhere else is there any indication that Swift is the *author*. Rather, the work is anonymous, and said only to be in the *manner* of Swift. Swift was of course a well known satirist, having published (for example) [An Argument Against Abolishing Christianity](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Argument_Against_Abolishing_Christianity) in 1708. That an aspiring satirist should emulate Swift is unsurprising.

But the work shows up in the Hathi Trust [catalog](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/008958621) with Swift listed as the main author and [Edward Ward](https://www.digitens.org/en/notices/ned-ward.html) listed as a related name. A note says "Sometimes attributed to Jonathan Swift or Edward Ward." However, I have been unable to find any scholarly work that attributes this essay to Swift—or indeed, to Ward. Perhaps the "Dr W———d" to whom the essay is dedicated is meant to be Ward, but that seems to point away from rather than toward Ward as the author.

The source cited in the linked question, Dominique Laporte's *History of Shit*, is Pierre Jannet et al.'s *Bibliotheca Scatologica*  (1849). This French work can be found on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bibliotheca_scatologica_ou_Catalogue_rai/Eo5aAAAAcAAJ). It does indeed attribute *The Grand Mystery* to Swift (see page 11), but it's unclear how reliable this attribution is (or even is meant to be). Jannet and his co-authors provide bibliographic information only for two different French translations of this essay.

Swift certainly [did write scatological works](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50579/the-ladys-dressing-room), but what scholarly evidence exists for attributing *The Grand Mystery* to him, or to Ward, or to anybody else? The same can be asked of *[The Benefit of Farting Explain'd](https://archive.org/details/bim_eighteenth-century_the-benefit-of-farting-e_puff-indorst-fart-in-ha_1722)* (1722), which is likewise occasionally attributed to Swift without any scholarly evidence adduced, but perhaps that should be a different question.

Comment: Sophie Vasset says that the pamphlet "targets the much satirised physician and natural historian John Woodward and his ideas on purging and vomiting" (*Murky Waters: British Spas in Eighteenth-century Medicine and Literature*, pp. 110–111, Manchester University Press). If this is right, then W–d refers to Woodward and not to Ward. Unfortunately, Vasset gives no argument for this claim.

Comment: The scan linked above might be read as "Dr. W------d" (that is, 6 missing letters), which is obviously consistent with "Woodward".